# Can I share Angular services across downgraded components used in my AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am slowly converting an AngularJs Application to Angular. I am following the hybrid app approach in the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-upgrademodule-with-angular-ngmodules
If I have a universal service, like a logger, can I share a single instance of that service between two downgraded components that are being treated as individual directives by angularJS? Currently I declare it in the providers array of both components individually, because there is no overall parent component since each downgraded component is its own Directive loaded into angularJS as needed, but I'm pretty sure this means I will have two separate instances running in my application and would like to avoid that if possible.